# Зеркалирование сайтов: юридический аспект

Tags: зеркало

Существуют ли законодательные ограничения, накладываемые на зеркалирование сайтов?

Поясню задачу. Одна из преимущественных сторон статей, опубликованных в интернете перед статьями, опубликованными на бумаге, состоит в том, что для обеспечения проверяемости информации можно вставить в текст ссылки, сразу переводящие на источник информации (так делается, например, в Википедии). Однако на многих информационных ресурсах (например, на новостных сайтах) информация хранится лишь ограниченное время, и со временем достоверность информации уже нельзя будет проверить по первоисточнику. Выходом из положения может быть зеркалирование веб-страницы и интеграция зеркала со своим сайтом.
Но существуют ли какие-либо законные ограничения, связанные с этим действием?

Приведу пример конфликтной ситуации. Опубликовал кто-то невыгодную для себя информацию, потом опомнился, и давай её удалять со своей веб-страницы. Но кто-то другой успел выполнить зеркалирование и добавить соответствующую ссылку на свою страницу. И всё. Дальше – только доказывать с помощью высокооплачиваемого адвоката ложный факт о том, что зеркалированная страница была отредактирована с целью клеветы.

Я слышал о таком праве, связанным с интернетом, как "право на забвение", хотя любому активному интернет пользователю понятно, что если информация особенная, то о ни о каком фактическом забвении не может быть речи.

Comment: Несмотря на то, что кто угодно может сразу обращаться в суд при виде нарушения своих прав (возможно, мнимого), никто так не делает. Это довольно дорогостоящее занятие, поэтому все обычно урегулируется в досудебном порядке. Знакомые, держащие сайт с сериалами, слышали много обещаний быть засуженными, но до суда никогда не доходило из-за своевременного разруливания конфликтов.